# How can I tell when I make an offhand punch attack?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I am working on a Hill Orc Gladiator of Uskayaw that uses a combination of one-handed axe and offhand punches to maximise hits per turn thus maximising piety gains thus putting that sweet, sweet +3 Invocations aptitude to a real good use. At least, that's a working theory.

The problem is, I can't tell *when* my character is making an offhand punch attack. This is problematic, since without knowing that I can't really gauge the effectiveness of my strategy and can't decide when to stop pouring loads of XP into Unarmed Combat skill.

I know that an untrained character without armour has a 33% chance of making an offhand punch, and that this chance goes up with Unarmed Combat and down with encumbrance (whose effects are reduced by sufficiently high Armor skill). However, when my most successful run had 8.0 in UC, 6.6 in Armor and a plate armour, I still couldn't quite pick out anything from `Ctrl+P` log that looked like offhand punches.

So: how can I tell when I make an offhand punch attack?

(Just to rule out rookie mistakes: I am **not using any shields: no buckler, no big shield, no great shield**. And the weapon is my starting war axe that you get with Gladiator background, so yes, it is one-handed.)

(I'm playing 0.19, not the current Trunk.)

Comment: Oh god. This is one of those things that is just not documented well. Honestly, your best option is to just check the source code. You can download the source for 19.5 here http://crawl.develz.org/download.htm or clone the git repo yourself from here https://github.com/crawl/crawl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a message, but the requirements to get an offhand punch with maximum frequency (that is, 33%) are:

- (str + dex) at least 50
- UC at least 20
- Body armor penalty at most 1
- Have a free offhand (no shield or 2h weapon, not sacrificed to Ru, etc.)

The first three scale in proportion to how close you are; the last is an absolute requirement to get offhand punches.

As an example, if your (str+dex) is 30, your UC skill is 10, your body armor penalty is 3, and your offhand is free, your chance to get an offhand punch with each attack is (30/50)*(10/20)*(1/3)*33% = 3.3%.

Source: http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Auxiliary_attack

Comment: Ah, that would certainly explain why I didn't see any (I completely misremembered the formula). I guess I need to either go read the source code to verify that the page is up to date, or play a couple of games with UC Troll while paying close attention to the log.

Comment: Anyway, I found out yesterday that the message itself is clear: `You throw a punch.`.